# Unsubscribe From RxJS Observable Impact

Tags: angular, rxjs

What is the impact of not unsubscribing from a RxJS Stream after it was completed? 
e.g. Angular 2 Http request.

Can this lead to a memory leak?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38008334/3055401

Comment: you can also implement automatically unsubscribe in angular. See this article: https://netbasal.com/automagically-unsubscribe-in-angular-4487e9853a88

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to unsubscribe from http requests because they complete immediately after the response/error arrived (and returned to the subscriber).

The impact will be the Observable / Subscription javascript variables not being garbage collected because they'll leave a reference, and will in turn create a memory leak.

It may or may not affect performance, depends on how many times a new Observable/Subscription is created and "left to rot".